How can I simulate a single Mass Spring Damper System in both vertical and horizontal Degrees of Freedom in Simscape?
I am using MATLAB R2023b Update 5. I am currently working on a simulation project in Simscape where I aim to model a cantilever beam with two degrees of freedom (DOF): one in the vertical direction and the other in the horizontal direction. While I have successfully modeled the vertical DOF, I am encountering difficulties in simulating the horizontal DOF effectively. I want to simulate both DOF simultaneously.[Here is what I have so far]

Modeling Approach: I have attempted various approaches to simulate both vertical and horizontal DOFs simultaneously. While I can achieve accurate vertical motion using translational mechanical elements aligned along the y-axis, I struggle to simulate independent horizontal motion along the x-axis.
Simulation Issues: When running simulations, the horizontal motion does not behave as expected. It appears that the horizontal DOF is not being properly captured or simulated, resulting in the same behavior as the vertical DOF

Ahh you may need to refresh your physics spring-mass dynamics. It happens.
Gravitational force has no effect on (vertical vs horizontal) motions, the spring will stretch if hanged or compress if flipped in vertical orientation but the motion remains the same given the disturbing force is the same and friction is zero in horizonal motion.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CYyOHGOPTXc&t=2s
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eqwn3j1lCIg
